Infer type of actions for `dispatch` using `reduxjs/toolkit`
I am using reduxjs/toolkit to set up my redux store and I would like to enforce that whenever dispatch is called, it only accepts actions that I have declared in my slices:
import { combineReducers, configureStore, createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
  value: false,
};

const testSlice = createSlice({
  name: "test",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    toggled(state) {
      state.value = !state.value;
    },
  },
});

const appReducer = combineReducers(testSlice.reducer);
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: appReducer,
});

const MyComponent = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  handleClick() {
     dispatch(someInvalidAction()) // does not complain
     dispatch(toggled())
  }
}

I am aware that I could just pass a generic typeof testSlice.actions to dispatch or have a combined union including all the action types like type AllActions = typeof testSlice.actions | typeof otherSlice.actions, but it feels like there should be a more straight forward way of doing this or perhaps someone knows the reason why it does not work like that out of the box?

Just don't do it. This simulates some kind of type safety that just doesn't exist in your application - internally, Redux will dispatch additional actions (e.g. INIT), and also all of your middleware might dispatch actions on their own.
Having the dispatch type of your store as shown in https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript#getting-the-dispatch-type is really the most realistic you can get.

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
})

export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch
export const useAppDispatch = useDispatch.withTypes<AppDispatch>()



I see this advice in  a number of places, but maybe I am missing something i.e. my goal with this would be to improve the developer experience:

When an action is dispatched, I would like typescript to give me the list of the actions that I have defined.
Based on the type of the action, typescript would tell me the shape of the payload that I need to provide for that action.

Is it still a bad idea to type dispatch for this purpose?

@Jacobdo if you use Redux Tookit slices, you get a fully typed action creator function for free. That hides the type as an implementation detail you never have to touch, and type-checks the shape of your payload. Also, a list of all action would grow way too long way too fast - just import the action creators from the right features in your application.

Slices are the way to go - I agree! In my use case, I have a big existing project where everything has been done manually - few action creators, most actions are typed "by hand". I am trying to avoid a big rewrite while enabling a slightly better developer experience around using dispatch.
